# jquery help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using autocomplete plugin in my form. I am using this autocomplete feature for a textbox inside a div, which is generated by AJAX, anyway autocomplete feature is working properly...I need your advice after selecting a an autopopulated data from textfield, I need to run a javascript function to take the selected data to fill in other column in the same div. So for that, i guess, i need to write  simply a function after the autocomplete data selection..
how will i do this....
thanx in advance.....

Comment: It would be a good idea if you show the code you already have.

Comment: Yes and you might read the documentaton on www.jquery.com. Everything explained with examples there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("waitimg").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("ajxform").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    $(function(){ $("#item_no").autocomplete("auto/finditem.cfm"); })
       }
  }

<div id="divid">
<input type="text" name="item_no" id="item_no">
 <input type="text" > 
</div>
```

so successful population of the div by the above ajax call, i am using autocomplete...

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using this plugin
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/
of if another plugin, maby you need a different event but:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
                        { 
                            document.getElementById("waitimg").innerHTML=""; 
                            document.getElementById("ajxform").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
                            $(function(){ 
                                $("#item_no").autocomplete("auto/finditem.cfm").result(function(event, data, formatted){
                                    $("#idOfOtherInput").html(formatted);
                                }); 
                            }) 
                        }
```

Haven't tested it, based on this example
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the autocomplete-widget from jQuery then you can use the "select" property in the construction like:

```
$("#textid").autocomplete({select: function(event, ui) 
{
    // put your code here to write the value into another control
    // for this use ui.item.value and ui.item.id
}
```